# Display some images on album cover in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xcode7

i want to display some images on album cover on my app like bellow image.
[image]

**EDIT:-**
i want to display this view in UICollectionViewCell and collectionView scrollDirection Horizontal with paging enabled.

any help will be appreciated. and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you looking for ? Are you asking to change apple's photo library album cover ? Or your own app ? Please clarify and also include the code that you have currently done for achieving this.

Comment: Your question is not rally clear, but from what I understand, this might help you. http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Comment: i edited my question & title. and i did not started code because i don't know, from how i start. so i can't give any code.

Comment: @humblePilgrim, can you please simplify that example ?i'm new to iOS

Comment: @Vat Can you please explain the scenario you are working on. Its vague right now and I  cannot understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @humblePilgrim, this is UICollectionViewCell with ScrollDirection Horizontal  and Paging Enabled

Comment: Ok, I gathered as much. Now if you go through the tutorial, you will see that you can use custom flow layout of UICollectionView for this purpose. I know the tutorial is a bit complicated for a beginner, but i really suggest you go through it and understand what's going on, as it will help you learn many more things.(from personal experience :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you understand the question correctly.
If you want to do what I see on the picture, so try this:

```
UIView *cover = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 500)];
cover.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
int width = 200;
int height = 350;

int posx = 100;
int posy = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //craete images
    UIView *imagebg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posx + arc4random_uniform(20), posy + arc4random_uniform(20), width, height)];
    imagebg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, width - 40, height - 50)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading-screen.png"];
    [imagebg addSubview:image];

    //rotate
    double rads = arc4random_uniform(100)/10;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imagebg.transform, rads);
    imagebg.transform = transform;

    //add as subview
    [cover addSubview:imagebg];
}

[self.view addSubview:cover];
```